# Problems installing Python Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am a beginning programmer trying to install the Python Protocol Buffers from this package: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protobuf-2.4.1.zip

The readme states:

1) Make sure you have Python 2.4 or newer.  If in doubt, run:

```
 $ python -V
```

2) If you do not have setuptools installed, note that it will be
   downloaded and installed automatically as soon as you run setup.py.
   If you would rather install it manually, you may do so by following
   the instructions on this page:

```
 http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#installation-instructions
```

3) Build the C++ code, or install a binary distribution of protoc.  If
   you install a binary distribution, make sure that it is the same
   version as this package.  If in doubt, run:

```
 $ protoc --version
```

4) Run the tests:

```
 $ python setup.py test
```

If some tests fail, this library may not work correctly on your
   system.  Continue at your own risk.

Please note that there is a known problem with some versions of
   Python on Cygwin which causes the tests to fail after printing the
   error:  "sem_init: Resource temporarily unavailable".  This appears
   to be a bug either in Cygwin or in Python:
     http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-07/msg01378.html
   We do not know if or when it might me fixed.  We also do not know
   how likely it is that this bug will affect users in practice.

5) Install:

```
 $ python setup.py install
```

This step may require superuser privileges.
   NOTE: To use C++ implementation, you need to install C++ protobuf runtime
   library of the same version and export the environment variable before this
   step. See the "C++ Implementation" section below for more details.

---

I have added both python and version 2.4.1 of protoc.exe into my PATH. However, when I try to run the test, I get an error message that says there's invalid syntax on line 38:

```
print "Can't find required file " + source
```

Okay, so it's missing parenthesis. I add them, and it encounters two more print statement syntax error messages. I fix those, and it encounters a syntax error message on an 'except' statement. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are using Python 3?

The code you refer to will only work in Python 2.X

Answer (score 1):

I have followed same steps , but I didn't get any errors.
Please make sure that you are getting correct Python and protoc version.

Export the environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.